# CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH is EMPTY?

Tags: cmake

I use cmake to generate visual c++ 11 project.
but, I wrote the following sentence in CMakeLists.txt
`MESSAGE(STATUS, "CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH = ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH}")`

result, the output is CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH =

why the "CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH" variable is empty? 
thinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think that it's because there's no centralised place where most applications install their include directories on Windows.

Generally applications keep their include directories within their own specific folder (often in %ProgramFiles% for example).  So there's really no meaningful value which could be applied to `CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH` on Windows.